# How do I get the rarer Pixballs?

Tags: eastward

How do I get the rarer Pixballs for *Earth Born* in *Eastward*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [wiki](https://www.eastwardwiki.com/Pixball) says:

> All pixballs aside from the final 5 can be collected from any machine
> using tokens from the beginning of the game. Playing through the main
> story will award the normal version of 'Fat Dragon'. The remaining 4
> pixballs - 'Sea Dragon', 'Bone Dragon', 'Asure Dragon', and 'Pixel
> King' (as well as their alternate versions and the alt of 'Fat
> Dragon') - are added to token machines after beating Earth Born for
> the first time. The 'Pixel King' is the most rare and may require a
> number of tries to win.